# How to print out the substring between two "|" in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to get the substring (spaces, ".", and 1) between the two "|".

I tried the following code:

```
f = open('test.txt', 'r')

with f:
    data = f.read()
    for line in data.splitlines():
        if line.startswith('Y='):
            m = re.search('| (.+?) |', line)
            if m:
                found = m.group(1)
            print(found)
```

But the only thing that printed out was "None."

**Text inside test.txt**:

[image: trying to read this text]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pipe `|` is a special character in regular expressions.

You can treat them as simple characters by enclosing them in brackets or escaping them.

```
m = re.search('[|] (.+?) [|]', line)
# or 
m = re.search(r'\| (.+?) \|', line)
```

It should now work as you intended.